# Has Cloudflare started filtering Russian traffic due to sanctions?

Tags: sanctions, geopolitics, internet

Today is 29 of march 2024.

Some sites using Cloudflare as a security or DNS service became blocked.

Can there be political reasons for this blocking?

How do I find out the legal grounds for this or future action?

**Сorrection**:

I'm not asking this question in vain. A number of companies in Russia received a month ago an internal letter from Microsoft that it is stopping access to Cloud services from March 28, 2024 due to sanctions. I'm sure Cloudflare has joined them, but I want to see the fact.

**My main question is:**

Is there any official list by which I can find out the companies like Cloudflare that have joined the sanctions against Russia?

Comment: Based on your edit it seems you are not asking about what Cloudflare has done rather what Microsoft has done. Any company that operates on the internet is allowed to filter who can access their services based on where they are in the world and if want to/can offer services in that area and they can even stop offering those services if things change but that is a business decision not a political one.

Comment: No, the question is solely about Cloudflare and edited the post to make it more accurate. Well, if the decision is political, I hope we will know about it soon.

Comment: I've voted to close. This question is solely about Cloudflare, which is a private company.

Comment: @JamesK I've edited my post, is it ok? or I have to create new question?

Comment: I don't think it is that Cloudflare is blocking Russia it is that induvial sites are blocking Russia to keep up with sanctions.  There are plenty of sites that use Cloudflare that are not actively doing anything that would be part of sanctions and there is no reason to believe that  those sites or Cloudflare is blocking the traffic in Russia. As an example I am sure plenty of news sites use it but don't block traffic in Russia.

Comment: It's not just Cloudflare. Virtually all platforms offer the organization the ability and choice to do such things.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this is technically true, I misunderstood that blocking is most likely the policy of a particular client site, and not Cloudflare as a provider. Otherwise, thousands of sites would be unavailable at the same time.

Comment: I don't think a new question is a good idea.  Your question asks for the reason that a private company is doing something.  But that's not a question of policy or politicians.  I don't know what the company is doing, but things that companies do are basically for business reasons.  Perhaps Cloudflare think that they will lose business in the US and Europe if they are associated with Russia.  Perhaps they think they will be hit by sanctions.  Now a question about sanctions is a matter of public policy, but a question about Cloudflare isn't.

Comment: Of course its well known that current US policy is antagonistic to Russia, and there are multiple levels of sanctions in place. So it may way be good economic policy for a company to disengage with Russian clients.  But that is not a political decision, it's a business decision, and one to which we are not party.

Comment: Cloudflare is not owned by Microsoft, AFAICT.

Comment: https://blog.cloudflare.com/steps-taken-around-cloudflares-services-in-ukraine-belarus-and-russia for their policy

Comment: This question lacks clarity. Which sites become blocked where? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: This is a legitimately unclear question.  If the law requires sanctions to be put in place, then they are not optional (or encouraged) for companies to follow.  Companies don't "join sanctions."  Sanctions are government actions.  Companies may be requires or not required to comply with government demands, depending on what those demands are.  So the actual question doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: @wrod: yeah the Q is too unclear as phrased. FWTW, there are ratings for companies in re their Russia 'decoupling', done by some academics.  https://som.yale.edu/story/2022/over-1000-companies-have-curtailed-operations-russia-some-remain Some companies have taken measures in excess of what official state sanctions demand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloudflare allows the site administrator to block any country of their choice. The interface is user friendly and easy to use.

This feature is normally used for blocking the DoS attacks originating from specific country but can be used to exclude the country administrator is not willing to provide the service to. Who owns the site and wants to deny Russia from its content, can make a personal decision and do this very easily.

When used in intended way, any country can get under "sanctions" but usually only as long as the attack continues.

Comment: Or the business in question simply desires not to do business with them. Even before the first invasion of Ukraine, discussions of blocking Russia (and some other countries) due to technical security threats was common in technical circles.

Comment: Some US retailers basically block most of the world. Some UK online businesses (newspapers, etc) also block EU to avoid compliance with GDPR.

Comment: There must be an official position of the company, formalized in some documents that can be read online. Otherwise, it turns out that the business simply does not respect its end customers.

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov If you are asking for an official position from a company that would mean it is a business decision and not a political one.

Comment: @JoeW It is naive to believe that the American government (which dictates the rules of the game, in particular for Cloudflare) does not affect business.

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov Yet your question talks about actions taken by Microsoft not Cloudflare. This site isn't to discuss what decisions a company makes and unless you have some sort of evidence that Cloudflare is blocking Russia as a whole this isn't on topic.

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov Technical security postures are usually not publicly documented. For good reason that is out of scope here. Cyber attacks are a constant occurrence. While blocking certain countries doesn't wholly stop the attacks, organizations have found it substantially reduces them, by more than the cost of lost business. In the US, the government cannot demand they not block the traffic. And any government demand that they *do* block traffic must and is public. The spectre of government control here is a result of personal bias.

Comment: @bharring Edward Snowden cannot agree with you.
The spectre of US government control is the world fact.

Comment: current DDOS https://unn.ua/en/news/slovenian-government-websites-are-subject-to-unusual-cyberattacks

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov You should probably read his leaks. He showed the US government was *observing* more traffic than thought. You're asserting the US government is forcing technical decisions on widespread, disparate groups.

Comment: @bharring You should probably know that "disparate" IT companies are under US government. Mr. Snowden revealed that the US is trying to moderate procesess none of US government's business, exactly the processes in other countries and private persons.
The question I asked is closed, so I'm closing our discussion. Thank you.

Comment: That's not how PRISM works. That's not how the US works. That's not how US business make this decision.

Comment: I have run websites in the US, without reporting to anyone. I have made the decision not to block any country. No US government interest had any part in this. Anyone in the US can spin up a website from scratch in an hour or three, and do the same.

Comment: Regardless of whether you think it is naive or not, there is the concept of the law being silent on a topic.  It means that the law simply hasn't addressed it.  In case the law is silent on whether a blanket sanctions regime should be imposed on the Russian Internet traffic, individual companies are free to do as they see fit.  The fact that the law is sometimes not silent wrt to Cloudflare does not mean that it always not silent.  Some decisions simply have causes other than the law.

Comment: "Refusal to deal" on the country and larger level is very common. For instance, many web shops do not ship to Switzerland, others only ship to the home country, paid web content may be country specific (including "this is not available in your country") and for DVDs even "regions" have been implemented as part of the official standard to make sure they will not be played where they should not. If this is wrong, still so widespread that nobody cares.